# Node-Red usb sensor

Tags: sensors, node-red, hid

I'm trying to capture sensor data from an [USB-sensor](http://www.magnet-physik.de/fileadmin/Mediendatenbank/1_Produkte/2_Messtechnik/Datenbl%C3%A4tter/HU_USB_Hall_Probes.pdf). The first problem is that Node-Red on the [device](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/658/109741658/att_899623/v1/iot2000_operating_instructions_e_en-US.pdf) I use doesn't accept the /dev/ttyUSB0 node that I would like to use in the project.

After reading some other forums, I found out that I can look after the correct name, using the `lsusb` command, and enter something like /dev/bus/usb/002/002 into the Serial Input Port. Now I got conformation that the sensor is or not connected.

But I didn't get any data out of it. I tried to do the same as in [this](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/intel-iot-gateway/tree/master/Getting%20Started%20With%20Node-Red%20and%20Omega%20RH-USB) project what is very similar to mine. But the debug output shows "Error: Error: Invalid argument, calling write".

Can someone help me out? I just wrote an e-mail to the manufacturer in order to get more data about how exactly the data comes in. With this new information I hope I can determinate which option to split I have to make (Split on character/split after timeout/split after size of buffer).

[image]

UPDATE--

I've got new information from the manufacturer. This device is an HID and doesn't make use of a virtual COM port interface. So this sensor will never work like the example above I guess. Currently I'm trying to install node-red-contrib-usbhid, I'm hopeful the gain access to the data with this wrapper.

UPDATE--

The installation of the HID-node isn't that easy. For the moment I'm skipping that part, and running Node-Red on my Windows-desktop. In this environment I'm just checking the possibility of HID-node without considering about the installation of these nodes. In Windows they are working. I'm receiving a 64 array buffer. Now I need to decode this array.

Is there a way to make use of the original dll-file from the manufacturer in Node-Red? The decoding is all involved in this dll-file.

I also did an conversion from the dll to an C# Visual Studio project. It's still hard for me to say which byte is responsible for the value of the sensor, but I hope I can decode the array with this information.

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely that this magnetic flux sensor will respond to the same input command (F) as the temp/humidity sensor in the project you are emulating. It looks like the manufacturer provides a custom program to communicate with the sensor -- you may be able to access that directly (if it's python) or talk to it through stdin/stdout.

Comment: Yep, that's why I send an Email to the manufacturer, to gain that specific information. The custom made programs are C# and VB, so that sounds like a dead end for me.

Comment: If you have some custom code in another language, you might want to share that with the Node-RED community. It is not beyond the realms of possibility that someone will be interested enough to have a go at translating it.

Comment: @JulianKnight the example code is really basic. But there is an dll-file used with functions to get data from the sensor, and that is not open source of course.

Comment: Ah, OK. Well it isn't beyond possibility that someone could unpick the DLL but sadly probably nobody with the skills and time in the NR forums. Well, the company that makes that sensor claims to give "personal service" so lets hope they do! Certainly their online support leaves a LOT to be desired.

Comment: A bit late I know but an additional thought. PowerShell is generally able to utilise DLL's and you can call a PowerShell script directly from Node-RED using the exec node.

Comment: Hm interesting point, I'll take a look at it thanks!